# CRUD com imagens , trabalhando com HttpPostedFileBase e byte[]

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, code-first

Estamos usando o EntityFramework com CodeFirst e DataBase PostgreSQL. Existem algumas tabelas que devem salvar imagens, e nas classes POCO estão referenciadas como byte array.

Até esse ponto tudo tranquilo. Eu consigo pegar as imagens com parâmetros HttpPostedFileBase e converter para `byte[]` para salvar no banco de dados. O problema é quando quero resgatar essa imagem do banco de dados e colocar ela no campo `<input type="file"/>` novamente.

A questão é como fazer para retornar essa imagem na View Edit no mesmo campo `<input type="file"/>`, tal como acontecem com os outros campos de tipo string, int, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por motivos de segurança, você não pode setar um arquivo como valor em um campo `<input type="file"/>`. O que pode ser feito, nesse caso, é colocar um `if` na sua `view`. Caso o arquivo exista no `model`, você renderiza uma tag `img` ou um link para download. Caso não exista, você exibe o `<input type="file"/>` para permitir o upload da imagem.

Comment: Entendi, e te agradeço pela solução. Mas e se eu quiser que ele altere a imagem? Como eu faria?

Comment: Nesse caso, você pode disponibilizar um link para exclusão da imagem, e logo em seguida, exibir novamente o <input type="file" /> para permitir ao usuário fazer o upload de uma nova imagem.

Answer (score 1):

Como o amigo comentou, por motivos de segurança você não vai conseguir fazer algo do gênero. Se você quer permitir que essa pessoa baixe a foto já feito upload normalmente você faz um objectURL e o navegador toma conta de fazer o download dela:

```
var file = new Blob([response.data], { type: 'image/bmp' });
var imageBlob = URL.createObjectURL(file);
window.open(imageBlob );
```

**Referência:** https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Blob